# Linux Script to check if process is running and act on the result

Tags: linux, bash, process, grep

I have a process that fails regularly & sometimes starts duplicate instances..

When I run:
`ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c "processname"`
I will get:
`2`
This is normal as the process runs with a recovery process..

If I get
`0`
I will want to start the process
if I get:
`4`
I will want to stop & restart the process

What I need is a way of taking the result of `ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c "processname"`

Then setup a simple 3 option function

```
ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c "processname"
if answer = 0 (start process & write NOK & Time to log /var/processlog/check)
if answer = 2 (Do nothing & write OK & time to log /var/processlog/check)
if answer = 4 (stot & restart the process & write NOK & Time to log /var/processlog/check)
```

The process is stopped with
`killall -9 process`
The process is started with
`process -b -c /usr/local/etc`

My main problem is finding a way to act on the result of `ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c "processname"`.

Ideally, I would like to make the result of that grep a variable within the script with something like this:

`process=$(ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c "processname")`

If possible.

Comment: What doesn't work with what you propose? It looks like the right syntax. (Though you might want to use `pgrep` if you have that.)

Comment: What you are doing is very fragile as the results of `grep` can be influenced even by unprivileged users. You should have a look at `monitd` or at least list only `root`s processes (or the daemon user)

Comment: OK, I tried `ps aux | grep "[p]rocess" but the result was more complicated than `ps x |grep -v grep |grep -c "process"` so I am not too sure how to interpret the printout & use it in my script..  In what scenario could the original grep be fragile?  I will be the only user ever logged into this server..  Also, how would I incorporate "list only roots processes (or the daemon user)" in the grep??  Thankyou for your time

Comment: Use **Systemctl** in linux. It is new way to monitor systemD services and Units. Learn more here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-systemctl-to-manage-systemd-services-and-units

Answer (score 80, accepted):

> ## Programs to monitor if a process on a system is running.

Script is stored in `crontab` and runs once every minute.

## This works with if process is not running or process is running multiple times:

```
#! /bin/bash

case "$(pidof amadeus.x86 | wc -l)" in

0)  echo "Restarting Amadeus:     $(date)" >> /var/log/amadeus.txt
    /etc/amadeus/amadeus.x86 &
    ;;
1)  # all ok
    ;;
*)  echo "Removed double Amadeus: $(date)" >> /var/log/amadeus.txt
    kill $(pidof amadeus.x86 | awk '{print $1}')
    ;;
esac
```

`0` If process is not found, restart it.
`1` If process is found, all ok.
`*` If process running 2 or more, kill the last.

---

## A simpler version.  This just test if process is running, and if not restart it.

It just tests the exit flag `$?` from the `pidof` program.  It will be `0` of process is running and `1` if not.

```
#!/bin/bash
pidof  amadeus.x86 >/dev/null
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
        echo "Restarting Amadeus:     $(date)" >> /var/log/amadeus.txt
        /etc/amadeus/amadeus.x86 &
fi
```

---

## And at last, a one liner

```
pidof amadeus.x86 >/dev/null ; [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Restarting Amadeus:     $(date)" >> /var/log/amadeus.txt && /etc/amadeus/amadeus.x86 &
```

This can then be used in crontab to run every minute like this:

```
* * * * * pidof amadeus.x86 >/dev/null ; [[ $? -ne 0 ]] && echo "Restarting Amadeus:     $(date)" >> /var/log/amadeus.txt && /etc/amadeus/amadeus.x86 &
```

cccam oscam

Comment: OK, I will test this and report back, The wild card might be usefull also in my case because there could be (3,5,6,7...) process's running and all of those results would be a problem.  Will the * in your script mean all instances of the process other than 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes, corrected my comment to reflect that. You should also try to use `pidof` instead of `ps`

Comment: I think you should additionally check who is the owner of the process

Comment: Not needed, since for this there always would be one owner and one process.

Comment: Very nice! Not sure if it's suitable for you, but depending on what linux you're working with, you might have specific tools to achieve a nice process monitoring (for instance, `procd` for OpenWRT, `daemontools`, etc.)

Comment: The `command; if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]` is an antipattern. The *purpose* of `if` and the shell's other flow control statements is to run a command and check its return code. The proper and idiomatic way to write that is `if ! command` (though the negation may not work in really old versions of the Bourne shell; just invert the `then` and `else` cases to be portable back into the late 1970s. However, of course, `[[` isn't Bourne-compatible anyway; so if you are targeting Bash specifically, this is not a concern anyhow).

Answer (score 8):

I adopted the @Jotne solution and works perfectly! For example for mongodb server in my NAS

```
#! /bin/bash

case "$(pidof mongod | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "Restarting mongod:"
    mongod --config mongodb.conf
    ;;
1)  echo "mongod already running"
    ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 5):

I have adopted your script for my situation Jotne.

```
#! /bin/bash

logfile="/var/oscamlog/oscam1check.log"

case "$(pidof oscam1 | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "oscam1 not running, restarting oscam1:     $(date)" >> $logfile
    /usr/local/bin/oscam1 -b -c /usr/local/etc/oscam1 -t /usr/local/tmp.oscam1 &
    ;;
2)  echo "oscam1 running, all OK:     $(date)" >> $logfile
    ;;
*)  echo "multiple instances of oscam1 running. Stopping & restarting oscam1:     $(date)" >> $logfile
    kill $(pidof oscam1 | awk '{print $1}')
    ;;
esac
```

While I was testing, I ran into a problem..
I started 3 extra process's of oscam1 with this line:
`/usr/local/bin/oscam1 -b -c /usr/local/etc/oscam1 -t /usr/local/tmp.oscam1`
which left me with 8 process for oscam1.  the problem is this..
When I run the script, It only kills 2 process's at a time, so I would have to run it 3 times to get it down to 2 process..

Other than `killall -9 oscam1` followed by `/usr/local/bin/oscam1 -b -c /usr/local/etc/oscam1 -t /usr/local/tmp.oscam1`, in `*)`is there any better way to killall apart from the original process? So there would be zero downtime?

Answer (score 0):

If you changed awk '{print $1}' to '{ $1=""; print $0}' you will get all processes except for the first as a result. It will start with the field separator (a space generally) but I don't recall killall caring. So:

```
#! /bin/bash

logfile="/var/oscamlog/oscam1check.log"

case "$(pidof oscam1 | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "oscam1 not running, restarting oscam1:     $(date)" >> $logfile
    /usr/local/bin/oscam1 -b -c /usr/local/etc/oscam1 -t /usr/local/tmp.oscam1 &
    ;;
2)  echo "oscam1 running, all OK:     $(date)" >> $logfile
    ;;
*)  echo "multiple instances of oscam1 running. Stopping & restarting oscam1:     $(date)" >> $logfile
    kill $(pidof oscam1 | awk '{ $1=""; print $0}')
    ;;
esac
```

It is worth noting that the pidof route seems to work fine for commands that have no spaces, but you would probably want to go back to a ps-based string if you were looking for, say, a python script named myscript that showed up under ps like

root     22415 54.0  0.4  89116 79076 pts/1    S    16:40   0:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/myscript

Just an FYI

Answer (score 0):

The 'pidof' command will not display pids of shell/perl/python scripts. So to find the process id’s of my Perl script I had to use the -x option i.e. 'pidof -x perlscriptname'

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get case to work at all.
Heres what I have:

```
#! /bin/bash

logfile="/home/name/public_html/cgi-bin/check.log"

case "$(pidof -x script.pl | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "script not running, Restarting script:     $(date)" >> $logfile
#  ./restart-script.sh
;;
1)  echo "script Running:     $(date)" >> $logfile
;;
*)  echo "Removed duplicate instances of script: $(date)" >> $logfile
 #   kill $(pidof -x ./script.pl | awk '{ $1=""; print $0}')
;;
esac
```

rem the case action commands for now just to test the script. the above pidof -x command is returning '1', the case statement is returning the results for '0'.

Anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong?

Solved it by adding the following to my BIN/BASH Script:
    PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Answer (score 0):

In case you're looking for a more modern way to check to see if a service is running (this will not work for just any old process), then *systemctl* might be what you're looking for.

Here's the basic command:

```
systemctl show --property=ActiveState your_service_here
```

Which will yield very simple output (one of the following two lines will appear depending on whether the service is running or not running):

```
ActiveState=active
ActiveState=inactive
```

And if you'd like to know all of the properties you can get:

```
systemctl show --all your_service_here
```

If you prefer that alphabetized:

```
systemctl show --all your_service_here | sort
```

And the full code to act on it:

```
service=$1
result=`systemctl show --property=ActiveState $service`
if [[ "$result" == 'ActiveState=active' ]]; then
    echo "$service is running" # Do something here
else
    echo "$service is not running" # Do something else here
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CentOS, no need to write a script and set cron job. Here is one of the smartest ways to ensure systemd services restart on failure.
Make following changes to /usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service

Then under the [Service] section in the file, add the following 2 lines:

```
Restart=always
RestartSec=3
```

After saving the file we need to reload the daemon configurations to ensure systemd is aware of the new file

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Read the following link for the complete steps -
https://jonarcher.info/2015/08/ensure-systemd-services-restart-on-failure/