# Bash - Check if a process is running, else start it and send a mail using "switch" case

Tags: linux, bash, email, cron, centos

So I have a little scriptlet which checks if a process is running and if not, starts the script and sends me a mail. The script I've written ([and is "inspired" from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162678/linux-script-to-check-if-process-is-running-act-on-the-result)) is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$(pidof webrtc2sip | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "Restarting WebRTC2SIP:     $(date)" >> /var/log/webrtc2sip.txt
    echo "Restarting WebRTC2SIP at $(date)" > test.txt
    /opt/webrtc2sip/sbin/webrtc2sip --config=/opt/webrtc2sip/sbin/config.xml &
    mail -r webrtc2sip@testserver.net -s "ALERT: webRTC2sip restarted" me@testserver.com  < test.txt
    ;;
1)  # all ok
    ;;
*)  echo "Removed multiple WebRTC2SIP: $(date)" >> /var/log/webrtc2sip.txt
    echo "Removed multiple WebRTC2SIP at $(date)" > test1.txt
    kill $(pidof webrtc2sip | awk '{print $1}')
    mail -r webrtc2sip@testserver.net -s "ALERT: webRTC2sip multiple processes killed"  me@testserver.com  < test1.txt
    ;;
esac
```

I set a cron for this to be executed every minute (`* * * * * /path/to/script`).

Now, what I believe is happening is, the first case is being executed repeatedly. I'm not sure because the `webrtc2sip` PID doesn't change but I keep getting the first mail "ALERT: webRTC2sip restarted" every minute.

Where have I made the mistake? Is there an error in the logic I've applied?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A more robust approach would be to run `webrtc2sip` using something like [daemontools](http://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html), which already solves the problem of ensuring a service remains running.

Comment: It seems like you are falling in the case *). What is the subject line of the email that you get every minute ALERT: webRTC2sip restarted or ALERT: webRTC2sip multiple processes killed?

Comment: @Gurubaran - sorry I didn't mention that - It's the first mail that I keep getting -edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd think Gurubaran is mostly right.  I think the root cause is your simple kill does not terminate the process (as happened to me when testing), so the number of running instances of webrtc2sip does not decrease.  Try `kill -kill` instead and see if that resolves your issue.

Also your code only deals with one additional instance of webrt2cip each minute.  This might be better:

```
case "$(pidof webrtc2sip | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "Restarting WebRTC2SIP:     $(date)" >> /var/log/webrtc2sip.txt
echo "Restarting WebRTC2SIP at $(date)" > test.txt
/opt/webrtc2sip/sbin/webrtc2sip --config=/opt/webrtc2sip/sbin/config.xml &
mail -r webrtc2sip@testserver.net -s "ALERT: webRTC2sip restarted" me@testserver.com  < test.txt
;;
1)  # all ok
;;
*)  echo "Removed multiple WebRTC2SIP: $(date)" >> /var/log/webrtc2sip.txt
echo "Removed multiple WebRTC2SIP at $(date)" > test1.txt
while [ $(pidof webrtc2sip | wc -w) -ne 1 ]
do
  kill -kill $(pidof webrtc2sip | awk '{print $1}')
done
mail -r webrtc2sip@testserver.net -s "ALERT: webRTC2sip multiple processes killed"  me@testserver.com  < test1.txt
;;
```

esac`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I thought so too.. If there are more than one processes then you want to make sure you want to kill them all... Else you will fall into this *) case more often than you anticipate. darylbnz solution should be working. You can also try 'kill -9' and make sure the process is killed.