# bash script not running as expected from cron vs. shell.

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron, fedora

I have a script I got from this website and modified to suit my needs. Orginal post: [Linux Script to check if process is running & act on the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162678/linux-script-to-check-if-process-is-running-act-on-the-result?newreg=92220ac44c1d4081ad522f3a789ea24f)

When running the script from cron, it always creates a new process. If I run it from shell it runs normally. Can anyone help me debug the issue ?

Script

```
[root@server2 ~]# cat /root/full-migrate.sh
#!/bin/bash

case "$(pidof perl | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "Restarting iu-maildirtoimap:     $(date)" >> /var/log/iu-maildirtoimap.txt
    /usr/local/bin/iu-maildirtoimap -i currentuser.txt -D imap.gmail.com:993 -d -n7 -I&
    ;;
1)  echo "Everything seems okay:     $(date)" >> /var/log/iu-maildirtoimap.txt
    ;;
*)  echo "Removed double iu-maildirtoimap: $(date)" >> /var/log/iu-maildirtoimap.txt
    kill -9 $(pidof perl | awk '{print $1}')
    ;;
esac
```

crontab job

```
[root@server2 ~]# crontab -l
*/1     *       *       *       *       /bin/bash /root/full-migrate.sh
```

From the logfile:

```
Removed double iu-maildirtoimap: Tue Dec 30 02:32:37 GMT 2014

Removed double iu-maildirtoimap: Tue Dec 30 02:32:38 GMT 2014

Removed double iu-maildirtoimap: Tue Dec 30 02:32:39 GMT 2014

Everything seems okay:     Tue Dec 30 02:32:39 GMT 2014

Restarting iu-maildirtoimap:     Tue Dec 30 02:33:01 GMT 2014

Restarting iu-maildirtoimap:     Tue Dec 30 02:34:01 GMT 2014

Restarting iu-maildirtoimap:     Tue Dec 30 02:35:01 GMT 2014
```

The first 4 entries are me manually running     `"/bin/bash /root/full-migrate.sh"`
The last 3 are from the crontab.

Any suggestions on how to debug this issue ?

At the time of writing:

```
[root@server2 ~]# $(pidof perl | wc -w)
bash: 13: command not found

[root@server2 ~]# $(pidof perl | awk '{print $1}')
bash: 26370: command not found
```

Comment: What does `pidof perl` output? Does using `/sbin/pidof` in the script "fix" the cron operation?

Comment: edit /root/full-migrate.sh and add: echo $PATH , it should be same your online $PATH , if not add it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your test from the command line is not valid, because you are basically executing the process id, which will give you a command not found.

From the command line you will need to test this way:

```
$ pidof perl | wc -l
```

without the `$()`

The issue you are most likely having is that cron cannot find pidof in the path. So you will need to figure out where pidof resides on your system:

```
$ which pidof
```

and then put that full path in your cron job and it should work.

Comment: StackSnippets are for content that can be executed in a browser. Use the `{}` button, not the snippet button, to code-format content in other languages.