# Can we Have a mutual monitoring threads?

Tags: linux, multithreading, process, thread-safety, pthreads

Let's say we have a thread A and a thread B.

How can we monitor state of thread A within thread B and vice versa?

Comment: Your question asks about threads, but you talk about processes. Which do you mean?

Comment: okay, sorry about the confusion.can we have the threads that can be monitored mutually ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "monitoring"?

Comment: i am thinking of a problem where thread A exits with some reason, i should be able to monitor state of the thread A from thread B or even manage its state like restart thread A and vice versa

Comment: you mean for example  ... program A sending data to machine M and Thread B read from same machine and you want to check from each program/script if other is running ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162678/linux-script-to-check-if-process-is-running-act-on-the-result   I think this would be useful tip

Comment: No I mean thread a running on a machine fails/exits abruptly thread B running on same machine should be able to restart the thread.