# How to check the java application (non spring boot) if it is up or down

Tags: spring, spring-boot-actuator

I have this requirement that I need to check if the java application (not web app) is running or down via bash script.
It is non springboot application as well. It is just a normal spring application that connects and listen to kafka, get the the object from the topic and call an API.

We thought of to use spring actuator to check the health however it is not a web application.
What is the recommended way to check a non-web and non-springboot application if it is up or down?

Please advise.

Comment: Health API should be used to check whether application is up or not

Comment: Hi @MandarDharurkar are you referring to spring actuator?

Comment: If you want do it via bash script then you can : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162678/linux-script-to-check-if-process-is-running-and-act-on-the-result

Comment: similar to spring actuator you can write your own health api which will just return 200 success . no need to import spring actuator as you mentioned it is not a spring application

Comment: I do agree with @lczapski approach too

Comment: @MandarDharurkar If I understood correctly, it is a Spring application, but not a web app. In that case you might still use Actuator, but access it via JMX. This can be achieved by using something like https://docs.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm. Just checking whether the process is still running might not be enough. With proper Actuator checks you can get more precise results, e.g. if the connection to the database is broken etc.

Comment: yes agree with you @CliveBixby ! it depends on what approach to take to solve this.