# while running ps -ef | grep 'keyword' in cmd, getting one output values but while running in ansible i am getting two output values

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-template

While running ps -ef | grep 'keyword' in cmd i am getting one output values, but while running same command in ansible playbook i am getting two outputs, i dont know why.

Note: process is not running

while running in command, I am getting output like this

```
user    4917 130211  0 00:20 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto keyword
```

while running in ansible playbook i am getting outputs like this

```
\user 2480   2477  0 07:02 pts/1    00:00:00 grep keyword
user 2477   2476 81 07:02 pts/1    00:00:00 /bin/sh -c ps -ef | grep keyword
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux Script to check if process is running and act on the result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20162678/linux-script-to-check-if-process-is-running-and-act-on-the-result)

Comment: What about using the [purposed `pids` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/pids_module.html) instead?

Comment: A really common way to do it in plain linux is [`ps -ef | grep "[k]eyword"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results), so the grep excludes itself.

Answer (score 0):

When you run `ps -ef | grep 'keyword'` the resulting list includes the `grep` command.

#### Suggesting to use command `pgrep`

```
pgrep -af 'keyword'
```

The output result is a list of lines:

```
pid 'command line that match RegExp pattern 'keyword'
```

If interested in `pid` only:

```
pgrep -f 'keyword'
```

If wants to store the `pid` in variable:

```
var1=$(pgrep -f 'keyword')
```

If wants to kill all the process:

```
pkill -9 -f 'keyword'
```